# How do I get MIN in Postgres to play nice with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Right now, I have an enormous query that I'm running in Rails:

```
@foo_collection = Foo.select('
    foos.id,
    array_agg() AS some_aggregate, -- about 20 of these, but they're not the problem
    MIN(bars.some_date), -- Returning wrong type - this is the problem
').joins('
    INNER JOIN bars... -- A LOT of joins - but also not the problem
').where('
    some_conditions
').group('
    foos.id
')
```

This query pulls the data I want according to PGAdmin. What is doesn't do is translate well into Rails. Trying to process `@foo_collection.some_date` as a `DateTime` object to create a time difference results in this:

```
undefined method `-' for "2014-04-01 16:12:35.461712":String
```

Is there any way to coax my PG output to give Rails a `DateTime` instead of a `String`, or will I have to tell Rails to parse all `some_date`s as `String`s?

So far, I've handled this by having Rails convert all `@foo_collection.some_date`s `to_datetime`, then `to_f` so that I can find time lapses between them. But this has significant overhead - It'd be much easier if I could just withdraw a `datetime` object straight from the DB.

Comment: PostgreSQL's aggregate function `min()` doesn't change the data type of its argument.

Comment: Weird. The query as I've written it in rails uses a .joins, a .where, and a .group on a model class. Pulling the field some_date returns a `String`. If this isn't a SQL problem, then why is Rails pulling a `String` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: You might want to edit your question and paste in the code for your model. Also try to cut down your query to the very least that still shows the odd behavior, and paste that in, too. As a DBA, I'd check the PostgreSQL schema first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't disclose the details of my DB other than the general structure. I'll try to elucidate this as much as I can within that constraint.

Comment: You don't need to share the details of your DB. Just check the schema to make sure the column bars.some_date is actually declared a date. Look at the PostgreSQL schema itself, not at your model.

Comment: According to PGAdmin3... `created_at` is a "timestamp without time zone," made by this statement `ALTER TABLE ng_flowcell_preps ADD COLUMN created_at timestamp without time zone;`

Comment: Then your problem must be in Rails, ActiveRecord, or your code. You can see `min()` behavior by executing `select min(created_at) from your_table;` in a SQL window within pgAdmin. The output pane will show the column name *and* data type, which should be "timestamp without time zone".

Comment: You are correct that running the query in PGAdmin returns a timestamp. Rails, on the other hand, just doesn't seem to get it: `Table.select('MIN(created_at) created_at').first.created_at.class => String`

Comment: What class does it return if you select only the column "created_at"? (Not using min().)

Answer (score 0):

Rails is most likely pulling the field as a string because you're not querying a model with a defined column type, I think your best bet might be to change the query to output to a table and then use a Rails model to query that table.